# Overlaying picture as texture over polygon shaped text

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using a layer for texture that gives a retro feel and a cloudy texture layer over some text I created using the polygonal lasso tool.

I now want to keep this texture overlay on the text layers, but remove it from the background. I tried using the quick selection tool, but I can't cut the text layers with the textured layers to make new copies. Any suggestions?

[image: texture polygonal lasso tool]

Here's my layers:

[image]

**Layer 1** is just a white background for some luminosity

**All** is each polygonal letter

**Layer 3** copy is the retro paper with mode overlay

**rough** is the cloud layer with 50% opacity and mode overlay

**Hue/Saturation 1** is a hue/sat layer for dulling saturation and increasing light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very simple solution to what you want to achieve - Clipping mask.

1. Put the texture just above your layer group. If you want to have your overlay layer beneath then I suggest that you duplicate that layer and put one below your group, and one between the group and the texture (as another clipping mask) - this will give you the same effect.
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> just between your group and the texture layers in the layer pallette. Doing this will make the above layer a clipping mask. When you hold your mouse over the border of the two layers and holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> you will see the cursor change to a different icon.
3. When you have your clipping mask, all the graphics the mask (the above layer) will be shown on the confinements of the underlying layer, in your case thats a layer group which means it will be included on all the layers within that group.

Here's a screenshot on how it will look when you're done.

[image: Clipping mask]

Here's a more in depth explanation on clipping masks: [Clipping masks tutorial](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/clipping-masks-essentials/)

Comment: Very helpful, and thank you for the clipping masks tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps after tinkering around for an hour:

1. Convert group ALL to a smart object so that all polygonal text layers are physically grouped.
2. We can now Ctrl + click on the smart object picture icon to select all layers
3. Right click and 'select inverse' in order to select all but text
4. Select 1 texture layer at a time and press delete. This will remove the background, but not on the smart object itself.